# Convert -130 to a 16 bits binary two's complement number

Tags: c, memory, binary, hardware

I know (130)base10 = 10000010,

Not sure how to go about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is complement(x) + 1, basically an xor and a sum:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    short mask = 0xFFFF; // 1111111111111111
    short data = 130;    // 0000000010000010
         // Complement      1111111101111101
         // Complement + 1  1111111101111110 = -130

    printf("%d\n", (mask ^ data) + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-130
```